# Giving more downvotes than upvotes?

Tags: feature-request, voting, down-votes

I recently looked at the Data.SE site.  After viewing other people's queries, I decided to write one of my own.  You see, I have only cast one downvote thus far in my SE career, but I have cast more than $610$ upvotes.  I was curious to see if this was typical: http://data.stackexchange.com/mathematics/query/94621/downvoters

It appears that *most* people cast more upvotes than downvotes.  However, there are some people who have cast significantly more downvotes than upvotes.  (This is more noticeable on SO than Math.SE.)

I mentioned this in chat, and someone suggested that the **system not allow someone to cast more downvotes than upvotes**.  I wanted to know the community's thoughts on this proposal--are there some downsides to this idea that I'm overlooking?

#### EDIT

It appears [there was once a policy](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/03/important-reputation-rule-changes/) that StackExchange had against casting disproportionately large numbers of downvotes.  However, that text in the blog entry is crossed out, so it makes me wonder why they changed.

Comment: User $-1$ would be in trouble: http://math.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community

Comment: +1 for the query, -1 for the feature...

Comment: Are there any *upsides* to this idea? You should really give some sort of reason when you make a feature request.

Comment: I'm not aware that this policy was ever in place. [Jeff Atwood proposed it and it was strongly rejected by the community](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/42601/should-we-have-a-policy-about-too-much-downvoting).

Comment: I think it's rather informative to be able to see which users behave this way (It seems to reveal something about the users.) Since the vast majority of people have a lot more upvotes, and the "reward" given by upvotes dwarfs the punishment delivered by downvotes, there does not seem to be a reason that downvoting needs hamstringing.

Comment: @ChrisEagle I probably should have marked this as a discussion rather than a feature-request... `:)`  I kinda wanted to see what others thought about downvoting more than upvoting, and if it needed to be discouraged.

Comment: Another person sent out in chat a query that sorts by relative downvotes, rather than net downvotes.  This is interesting as well: http://data.stackexchange.com/mathematics/query/94936/downvoter-relative-to-upvotes?NumOfUsers=40

Comment: By the way, essentially this same query already existed.  You can just search for it.  I have used it many times.

Comment: @Graphth Oh.  Thanks. `:)` I think you're referring to this one: http://data.stackexchange.com/mathematics/query/94938/downvoters-hall-of-shame-by-percentage

This *is* equivalent to the relative downvote query (oops).  My original one is unique as far as know, though.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Some questions, and especially answers, should be downvoted.  If we put in a policy further discouraging downvotes, it may mean that some of those necessary downvotes will no longer occur.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what accepting means in meta, but I think that I'm using it right.  This answer is getting several upvotes (and none down), and thus I think it voices the community's  opinion on the topic.  I also think it makes a good point, and gives a good reason on why a policy change like that should not be enacted.

Comment: @anorton he ones who significiently have more downvotes than upvotes are by definition called sourballs :-P